# ¿Cómo sumar fechas en formato dd-mm-yyyy y no tener en cuenta fines de semanas o fiestas en SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo una tabla llamada Feriados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y otra tabla Corresponsables:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero sumar por ejemplo una fecha de ahora(dd-mmm-yyyy), y sumarle los días que haya en (dias_valor de Corresponsables), pero si por ejemplo hay un fin de semana por medio o en la tabla de Feriados está el país_id que corresponde a ese días valor que no cuente ese día de fiesta tampoco. No sé como podría hacer esto. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Raras veces se puede usar la etiqueta [sql] sola, debería venir acompañada con la del motor de base de datos que este usando ¿es postgresql?

Comment: Y por cierto, agrega la estructura de la tabla de Feriados no una impresión de pantalla, en lo posible arma un caso de uso por ejemplo en https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6, lo que pides no es  complicado, pero tampoco trivial, ¿has intentado algo? trata de poner un poco más de esfuerzo en tu pregunta, por que de este lado pareciera que es del tipo "hagan mi tarea", no digo que lo sea, solo que lo parece.

Comment: diría que es casi imposible de responder sin saber el motor... en preguntas de SQL siempre utiliza etiquetas para indicar el motor.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Utilizo Postgresql, no he intentado nada porque ni si quiera se cual es la mejor manera de empezar para hacer algo así

Comment: @jachguate Disculpa, es Postgresql

Answer (score 3):

Probablemente haya maneras de hacer esto utilizando funciones de fecha que en general dependen del motor que utilizas.

Otra forma sería tratar de lograr una tabla con todas las fechas del año que **no** son ni fin de semana **ni** feriado con un ordinal.

De esa forma, sólo te faltaría buscar la fecha de ahora en esa tabla, obtener el ordinal y sumarle los dias_valor para obtener la fecha que buscás.

Si fuese `SQL Server` podrías hacer algo así también:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_TraerDiasLaborables](@FechaDesde date,@Cantidad int, @Pais int)

RETURNS @Fechas TABLE

(    
  fecha date primary key   
)

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @cnt int =0

if DATEPART(DW, @FechaDesde) not in (1,7) 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Fechas (Fecha) VALUES (@FechaDesde)
    SET @cnt = 1
END

DECLARE @NuevaFecha as date = @FechaDesde

WHILE @cnt<@Cantidad
BEGIN
    set @NuevaFecha =DATEADD(day,1,@NuevaFecha)

    IF  DATEPART(DW,@NuevaFecha ) not in (1,7) AND not exists (select 1 from Feriados where pais_id=@Pais and fecha_feriada = @NuevaFecha)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @Fechas (Fecha) values ( @NuevaFecha)
        SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
    END
END
 RETURN 
END
GO

y luego:

select 
    f.fecha
from
[dbo].[fn_TraerDiasLaborables](getdate(),(select c.dias_valor from Corresponsal c where c.id = 1),1) f
```

Comment: Buenas, gracias por su respuesta, pero en SQL Server no me sirve, debería ser en SQL plano o Postgresql

Comment: Postgresql también maneja funciones que devuelven tablas (https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/plpgsql-function-returns-a-table/) así que podrías hacer lo mismo. En Sql plano no creo que pueda lograrse, salvo que tengas una tabla pre-cargada con todas las fechas del año ya calculadas, cómo lo mencioné en la respuesta...  Saludos

Comment: Diego, en la comunidad se trata que las preguntas no sean multi etiquetas, un lenguaje, un motor, por eso es importante confirmar esto antes de responder, esta respuesta, por lo que dice el autor ahora ya no es válida. Por otro lado, la función está bien, pero va a tener problemas con configuraciones regionales por que asume que el domingo es el primer día de la semana y de acuerdo a la región esto no siempre es así.

Answer (score 0):

Esta query le suma a la fecha actual la cantidad de días especificada en la columna `dias_valor` (para cada fila de la tabla `corresponsables`) pero sin contar los fines de semana y feriados (según el país).

Utilicé una query recursiva, que va decrementando la cantidad de días cuando no son ni fines de semana ni feriados.

```
WITH RECURSIVE dias AS (SELECT id, current_date AS fecha, c.pais_id,
                               CASE WHEN extract(dow from current_date) IN (0, 6)
                                         OR f.fecha_feriado IS NOT NULL THEN dias_valor ELSE dias_valor - 1 END AS dias_restantes
                        FROM corresponsables c
                        LEFT JOIN feriados f ON current_date = f.fecha_feriado AND c.pais_id = f.pais_id
                        
                        UNION ALL 
                        
                        SELECT id, (fecha + INTERVAL '1 day')::date AS fecha, d.pais_id,
                               CASE WHEN extract(dow from (fecha + INTERVAL '1 day')::date) IN (0, 6)
                                         OR f.fecha_feriado IS NOT NULL THEN dias_restantes ELSE dias_restantes - 1 END AS dias_restantes
                        FROM dias d
                        LEFT JOIN feriados f ON d.fecha = f.fecha_feriado AND d.pais_id = f.pais_id
                        WHERE dias_restantes >= 0)
                        
                        
SELECT id, max(fecha)
FROM dias d
WHERE dias_restantes >= 0
GROUP BY id;
```

Probala, puede que requiera algún ajuste.